# SSRS 2008 Error Exporting to Word - Body is too complex

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word

I have a simple report that has been in production for several years but now is throwing an error when trying to export it to Word (no other reports get this error when exporting to Word, just this one).

The error is:

> An error occurred during local report processing. The Body is too complex to export to Word. Please group the ReportItems together into rectangles to simplify.

Nothing has changed anywhere, and I cannot find an answer to this anywhere.  The report has only 1 table on it, with 10 columns, and the rest is text boxes (it is a print of an order, so the order header info is at the top, and a table containing all the items on the order is below).  Can anyone here help?

Comment: may be your reporting services got updated to 2012, so word format changed from doc to docx.

Comment: no, they have not been updated :( and the other Word exports work, just this particular report is throwing the error so I don't have a clue :(